# Can't find homebrew installed app

Tags: git, homebrew

I just installed homebrew on a new Mac with Snow Lion.  The Mac already had git installed in /usr/bin/git (presumably when I installed Xcode command-line tools).

Anyway I ran:

```
$ brew install git
```

The command seemed to run successfully, installing git in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.1.5/bin/git
```

But in terminal, I'm getting the old git, not the homebew git:

```
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

What am I missing? Do I need to prepend /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.1.5/bin my PATH? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brew Doctor to the rescue:

```
$ brew doctor
Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    git
    git-cvsserver
    git-receive-pack
    git-shell
    git-upload-archive
    git-upload-pack

Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin in your PATH.
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type a command in your terminal, it looks for it in a variable called `PATH`. You need to put a directory where Homebrew puts symlinks to actual executables before all other directories in your `PATH`. Run this command:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

And restart your terminal.